# Android ADB connect over TCPIP not working

Tags: android, adb

I Connected my moto g2(Lollipop) to adb over WIFI using the commands

```
adb tcpip 5555
adb connect 192.168.2.6:5555
```

It was successfully connected

when i checked how many devices are connected.
It was showing 2 devices.

1.Device over USB

2. Device over WIFI with the IP address

So i need to use the device with WIFI So i unplugged the usb

**To my Shock both devices are disconnected.** I dont why? Please Help me

Comment: i tried many times.but no use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restart the adb connection with an `adb kill-server` then you should be able to reconnect and see your device with `adb devices` again.

Sidenote: I like [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.wifiadb&hl=en) to use adb over wifi.

Comment: I dont why. But this app saves me. Thank you